# How to return columns as element names instead of field elements with name attributes

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xslt

I'm exporting data from SQL Server in XML with the ultimate goal of transforming it with XSLT.  What I'd like to do is to be able to use  and reference the exported data by element name.  The output of my XML data is like this:

```
<field name="InvoiceNo">641718</field>
```

I'd like it to instead have the element name:

```
<InvoiceNo>641718</InvoiceNo>
```

I've got 3 functions.  A function that builds the header, one for the details, and one that exports the entire invoice to XML.

Here is the function that builds the XML.  I tried different variations to get this to work but I could not come up with the correct syntax.  This of course assumes that making this change now will make it easier to do XSLT in the future should additional transformations be needed.  Otherwise I could use something like `field[@name = "CustomerPO"]` in my XSL.

```
DECLARE @Invoice XML
       SET @Invoice =
       (SELECT 
        (SELECT [field/@name] = 'InvoiceNo' , [field] = InvoiceNo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SONo', [field] = SONo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'CustomerPO', [field] =CustomerPO FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'InvoiceDate', [field] = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,InvoiceDate,102),'.','-') FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'DueDate', [field] = DueDate FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipVia', [field] = ShipVia FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipViaAcctNo', [field] = ShipViaAcctNo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'FOB', [field] = FOB FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShippedDate', [field] = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,ShippedDate,102),'.','-') FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'OurRef', [field] = OurRef FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'YourRef', [field] = YourRef FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Project', [field] = Project FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'CustType', [field] = CustType FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Terms', [field] = Terms FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'DomesticAWB', [field] = DomesticAWB FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'IntlAWB', [field] = IntlAWB FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Origin', [field] = Origin FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Transport', [field] = Transport FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Nationality', [field] = Nationality FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'TripFlight', [field] = TripFlight FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'OurContact', [field] = OurContact FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Phone', [field] = Phone FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Fax', [field] = Fax FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Email', [field] = Email FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillTo', [field] = BillTo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToAttn', [field] = BillToAttn FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToAdd1', [field] = BillToAdd1  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToAdd2', [field] = BillToAdd2 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToAdd3', [field] = BillToAdd3 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToCity', [field] = BillToCity FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToState', [field] = BillToState FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToZip', [field] = BillToZip FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToCountry', [field] = BillToCountry FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToTelephone', [field] = BillToPhone FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BillToFax', [field] = BillToFax FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldTo', [field] = SoldTo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToAttn', [field] = SoldToAttn FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToAdd1', [field] = SoldToAdd1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToAdd2', [field] = SoldToAdd2 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToAdd3', [field] = SoldToAdd3 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToCity', [field] = SoldToCity FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToState', [field] = SoldToState FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToZip', [field] = SoldToZip FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToCountry', [field] = SoldToCountry FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToTelephone', [field] = SoldToPhone FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SoldToFax', [field] = SoldToFax FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipTo', [field] = ShipTo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipTAttn', [field] = ShipToAttn FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToAdd1', [field] = ShipToAdd1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToAdd2', [field] = ShipToAdd2 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToAdr3', [field] = ShipToAdd3 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToCity', [field] = ShipToCity FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToState', [field] = ShipToState FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToZip', [field] = ShipToZip FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToCountry', [field] = ShipToCountry FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToTelephone', [field] = ShipToTelephone FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'ShipToFax', [field] = ShipToFax FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Subtotal', [field] = Subtotal FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Discount', [field] = Discount FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Taxes', [field] = Taxes FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Misc1', [field] = Misc1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Misc2', [field] = Misc2 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Misc3', [field] = Misc3 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Misc4', [field] = Misc4 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Misc5', [field] = Misc5 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Misc6', [field] = Misc6 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'TaxA', [field] = TaxA FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'TaxB', [field] = TaxB FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'FixedMessage', [field] = FixedMessage FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        ,(
           SELECT 
             (SELECT [field/@name] = 'Line', [field] = Line FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'PartNumber', [field] =  PartNumber FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Description', [field] =  Descr FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'PickTicketPackingSlipNo', [field] =  PickTicketPackingSlipNo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Notes', [field] = Notes FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'NSN', [field] =  NSN FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'SerialNo', [field] =  SerialNo FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Cnd', [field] =  Cnd FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'FAA', [field] =  FAA  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'QtyOrdered', [field] =  QtyOrdered FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'UOM', [field] =  UOM FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Shipped', [field] =  Shipped FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'BackOrder', [field] =  BackOrder FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'UnitPrice', [field] =  UnitPrice FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            ,(SELECT [field/@name] = 'Amount', [field] =  Amount FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        FROM dbo.fnInvoiceDetail(@DOC_NO) FOR XML PATH('detail'), TYPE--, ELEMENTS
        ) as 'Detail' 
    FROM dbo.fnInvoiceHeader(@invoiceNo)
    FOR XML PATH('header'),TYPE 
    ,ROOT('invoice'))

RETURN @Invoice
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946050/converting-a-flat-xml-to-a-nested-xml

Answer (score 3):

If you just query your table as simple as possible you will get what you want.

Try something like this instead.

```
declare @T table
(
  InvoiceNo int,
  SONo int
)

insert into @T values
(641718, 1),
(641719, 2)

select InvoiceNo,
       SONo
from @T
for xml path('header'), root('invoice')
```

Result:

```
<invoice>
  <header>
    <InvoiceNo>641718</InvoiceNo>
    <SONo>1</SONo>
  </header>
  <header>
    <InvoiceNo>641719</InvoiceNo>
    <SONo>2</SONo>
  </header>
</invoice>
```